# What is the best time to upgrade to Town Hall 11?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Currently I am at TH 10. My Barbarian King and Archer Queen are both level 40, but my Defense is not very advanced; it is now halfway to being maxed. All of my walls and most of my troops are maxed out.

Should I wait to finish maxing my defense or just forward to TH 11?

FYI: I want to push trophies.

Answer (score 2):

What I strongly recommend is that **you do not upgrade you Town Hall until you maxed everything else**. Your troops, heroes and more importantly ***defense*** should be maxed before you upgrade your Town Hall, for the simple reason that it will be way harder to farm for you (remember that you're going to earn 75% of the total loot available on any level 10 Town Hall you meet during raid search).

The exception is for lava walls (level 11), they have a high price/efficiency ratio so it's "OK" if you bypass them for that level. But  still, you should have all your walls *at least* upgraded at level 10.

General tip : Do not rush into maxing your Town Hall, at any level. You'd do better to max everything else before upgrading to the next level.

Answer (score 0):

Just max out everything then upgrade TH. What i did was bit different. I max all the mines and collector and then i had to just upgrade other without falling short of resources.